# Find radius of half circles to find lowest production price

Tags: calculus, area

A company is making a new mirror that has the shape of a rectangle with a half circle on each side (making it look kinda like an oval shape). The area is 1 square meter. Around the mirror there is a frame. The frame around the circles are double the price to produce than that of the straight sides. What is the radius of the half circles that gives you the lowest production price?
I've named the radius *r*, the height of the rectangle *2r*, and the length of the rectangle *b*.
I've tried to use the definitions of the area and circumference to figure out some of the unknown variables, but I keep getting it messed up.
Can someone help me? Thanks

Edit:
Ok, so after taking a break and coming back to work on it, I think I have it figured out.
A=2rb+πr^2=1m^2
r(2b+πr)=1m^2
2b+πr=(1m^2)/r
2b=(1m^2)/r-πr

P (price of production) = 4πr+2b
P = 4πr + (1m^2)/r-πr
P = 3πr + (1m^2)/r
P' = 3π + (1m^2)/(r^2)

P'=0
3π + (1m^2)/(r^2)=0
And solve for r.
I got the answer **square root((1m^2)/3π)** = 0.3257m = 32.57 cm

Does that make sense?
When I graph the function, it looks right to me.

Comment: Why not show your work, so people can see what it is you understand about the problem and where you are getting stuck? That would be great.

Comment: Is the answer $R=r=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi+4}}$?

Comment: This looks very correct. May be, you could leave $A$ up to the end (instead of having these $(1m^2)$) and replace $A=1$ at the end.

Comment: Yes, that would definitely be easier, thanks!